# n-Queens - Logic Error - determining a vertical threat

Tags: list, lisp

In this program I will be determining if placing a queen will cause a threat on the board. This will use positions 1 - 8 (could be expanded) as the rows and columns. If no piece is located in a column then the y for that row will be 0 (otherwise it is the corresponding y). An empty board would be as follows: ((1 0)(2 0)(3 0)(4 0)(5 0)(6 0)(7 0)(8 0))

I wrote the following program to determine if a given move will result in a vertical threat:

```
(defun THREAT? (x y)
    (not (eq
        (cdr (nth (car x) y ))
         0
        )
    )
)
```

And this will be my input:

(THREAT? '(1 3) '(1 0)(2 4)(3 7)(4 3)(5 2)(6 8)(7 5)(8 1))

My idea with this is that I grab the car of the first argument (the x value that I am checking) use that to access the correct element in the second list and find the cdr of that element which will give me its y value. Then I check if it is 0 or not and if it is not 0, then it will be a threat. **I have yet to add functionality for checking horizontal and diagonal so I suspect I could easily achieve this through either conditionals or if statements but I want to clear up issues in my understanding of this before moving on**

My error is the following:

*** - EVAL: 2 is not a function name; try using a symbol instead

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

---

After fixing that error I found that my program will always return true. when inputting '(1 3) '((1 0)...) it will return true despite the fact that (1 0)'s 0 should find that it is equal to 0, returning true and then negating the true thus returning false and yet my program will always return true.

Edit: Fixed previous error message

Comment: Why don't you check what NTH and CDR returns? That's easy. Lisp is an interactive system. You can ask Lisp what expressions like `(cdr '(1 2))` returns. You should spend some time to understand what your code does. Good luck!

Comment: @John don't remove the original question. This invalidates any answer given. At the most, append your new findings at the end, separated by a horizontal rule. Better yet, ask a new question. It doesn't cost any more, to ask two questions or three, ... :-)

Comment: @OlafDietsche fixed my question to what it used to be and added a horizontal line to separate the error that I got after fixing. If this was not the correct way then I will fix it or ask a new question about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see why `(threat? '(1 3) '((1 0) (2 4) (3 7) (4 3) (5 2) (6 8) (7 5) (8 1)))` returns true, you must look at the definition of [`nth`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/nth.html)

> Note that the elements are numbered from zero, not one.

So, `(nth 1 '((1 0) (2 4) (3 7) ...))` returns `(2 4)` (here we are again :-) and not `(1 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from the third argument `(2 4)`, which is correct, because 2 is not a function name.

Lisp evaluates all arguments before passing it to a function. In the case of `(2 4)`, it searches for a function named 2 and fails. The same would happen with the remaining unquoted arguments.

Your `threat?` function expects only two arguments, so I suppose, this should be something like

```
(threat? '(1 3) '((1 0) (2 4) (3 7) (4 3) (5 2) (6 8) (7 5) (8 1)))
```

Comment: Yes, this did clear up the error message that I was getting. But for some reason it will always return true. If the y is not 0 then then my program should find that it is a threat in that column and vice versa, but when testing '(1 3) '((1 0)...) it will still return true when it should find that (1 0)'s 0 does equal 0, and will negate the answer thus returning false. Any ideas on this logic error?